# angular 2 show/hide router-outlet and redirect to html page

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, typescript

I have created a simple application. I have AD windows authentication web api which is on different domain so I have enabled cors. I have created a spike of api and returning 401 when not authorized.

> app.service.ts

```
authenticateUser(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:36655/", { withCredentials: true })
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

> app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(appService: AppService) {
        appService.authenticateUser()
            .subscribe(response => {

                //do something here because its not 401
            },
            error => {
                if (error.indexOf("401") >= 0)
                    console.log("Redirect to contact page")
                else {

                }
            });
    }
}
```

There are 2 things I am struggling with

1. how do I hide Router-Outlet (reason is I don't want to show my main page/links)
2. I can hide it using [hidden] on the main div but then how do I redirect? because `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will be invisible

> app.component.html

```
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['']">Home</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/factory']" id="factory" name="factory">Factory</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/supplier']" id="supplier" name="supplier">Supplier</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/businessarea']" id="businessArea" name="businessArea">Business Area</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have access all or no-access authentication that's why I dont want to show anything. Is there something like

`router.navigate('../shared/contact.html')`?

***Edit 1:***

> app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    private isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        this.authService.authenticateUser()
            .subscribe(response => {
                if (response.status == 200)
                    this.isAuthenticated = true;
            },
            error => {
                if (error.indexOf("401") >= 0)
                    this.isAuthenticated = false;
            });
    }
}
```

> authguard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    private isActive: boolean = true;
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        this.authService.authenticateUser()
            .subscribe(() => {},
            error => {
                if (error.indexOf("401") >= 0) {
                    let link = ['contactus'];
                    this.router.navigate(link);
                    this.isActive = false;
                }
            });
        return this.isActive;
    }
}
```

> auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {  
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    authenticateUser(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:5002/api/v1/authenticate", { withCredentials: true })
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(response: Response) {
        let body = response;
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.toString();
        }
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['']">Ethos</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" *ngIf="isAuthenticated">
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/factory']" id="factory" name="factory">Factory</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/supplier']" id="supplier" name="supplier">Supplier</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/businessarea']" id="businessArea" name="businessArea">Business Area</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

> app.routes.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    { path: 'factory', component: FactoryFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    //...some other
    { path: 'contactus', component: ContactUsComponent }
];
```

> AuthenticateController.cs

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) : new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
```

I can hide the menu fine but homeComponent which is search textbox renders before authentication, I want to hide everything and just want to show Logo. this search for factory textbox should not be displayed and there is data like gridview at the bottom which i am not showing in this picture.

[image]

It does not redirect until Cancel is clicked...another solution is just like I hid the menu I do it on homeComponent but there are many authService calls going around which is not elegant i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular 2 Routes you have 'CanActivate' and 'CanActivateChild' property.
This can be used for authorization before rendering the component.

You can find the usage here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

In your case, you do not have to remove the router-outlet.

Instead:

1. Add only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html.
2. Provide 2 routes

   1. Default route for your main component which requires authorization.
   2. A separate route(/contact) for your contact component which is linked with the contact.html.

      Import RouterModule in app module to add routes.
      example:

      ```
      RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
          path: '',
          canActivate: [AuthGuard] //provide the Injectable class here to authenticate.
          component: MainComponent
      },
      {
          path: 'contact',
          component: ContentComponent
      }
      ])
      ```
3. Create an @Injectable class as a guard to authenticate the user. This will call the app service to authenticate the user and redirect to contact component if unauthorized.
   You can use `this.router.navigate(['contact']);` import Router from "@angular/router"
4. Add this new @Injectable class as the CanActivate property for your default route.

Comment: thanks I will try this today, I am not sure about point number 3 why we need that...

Comment: how to add multiple routes? app route and child route?

Comment: Point 3: This is to provide and AuthGuard. It is a class created to to check for authentication. So that if you require authentication for any number of routes, you can just give this class as the CanActivate property for all those routes.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you multiple routes. Both routes are intended to load into the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` of app.component. _domain.com_ will load the default route and _domain.com/contact_ will load the second rout

Comment: thanks for suggestions but I am stuck at displaying menu, how should I display navbar after authgard etc. first request doesn't show anything authenticate and move to contact if required. if authenticated show navbar and content at bottom

Comment: router-outlet loads the page and shows the data which is unwanted behaviour because if user has no access then he/she should not be able to view even the menu/data

Comment: I need to do all this before rendering Router-Outlet i believe, and show/hide menu as well

Comment: how did you implement the authguard? Did you make an async service from authguard function? Because async will not work in authguard. AuthGuard needs to return true or false. if You can return true if the user is authenticated then the control proceeds to the corresponding route and if the user is not authenticated you can redirect to the contact page and returned false so that it stops the current flow to the current route and redirect to the contact route.

Comment: I implemented exactly the same way as in provided link but AuthGuard subscribes to auth.service which calls the authenticate method. I will edit my answer later on and you can tell if I am using right approach

Comment: please see my Edit 1 and you will get the idea what i am saying.

Comment: @KamranPervaiz The issue is your service call in the authguard is async. `if (error.indexOf("401") >= 0) {
                    let link = ['contactus'];
                    this.router.navigate(link);
                    this.isActive = false;
                }` This will be called only after `return this.isActive` so that it always return true. In authguard either do a Synchronous call or fetch your authentication condition from some local like cookie. If you need to fetch from cookie, you should have set the cookie some time before the route navigation.

Comment: but i cannot make authservice call synchronous it has to come from http call. is there anyway I can achieve that?

Comment: @KamranPervaiz our comments are getting longer :) . Anyway, The only other way that I can think of, as I mentioned earlier, is to get the authentication condition from localstorage or cookie. This local location should have been updated earlier by checking the service. Depending on your application you will have to find out a place where you can authenticate the user before loading this page. May be on a welcome page before showing the logged in page (Just my thought).